# What happens if validation/real data has values outside training set limits for continuous data?

Tags: validation, continuous-data

#### Describing

Example:

If feature X1 in training data has values inside [0,1]
However, X1 in real/validation data has values [-1, 2[

What happens then?

---

#### Previously discussed

On previous discussions with colleagues, it was suggested that it varies a lot depending on the model.

A linear model could explode this feature as it gets higher and the opposite for lower values.
A neural network would depend on its activation functions. ReLU based architectures would be more sensitive to these out-of-bounds values, and sigmoid based architectures would be less. However, we could not come to a conclusion when the architecture was a mix of both.

#### Literature

Are there any papers discussing this?

Comment: I'm afraid "it varies a lot depending on the model" is probably the best you can say...

Comment: @StephanKolassa do you recommend any papers discussing this for some set of models?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, sorry.